# .bash_login not executing

Tags: configuration, bash

I've put a `.bash_login` file in my `$HOME`-directory but it doesn't execute. I've also tried `.bash_profile` but also doesn't work. There are also

- .profile
- .bash_history
- .bash_logout

Any idea? I'm using Crunchbang 10 Statler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash only looks for .bash_login or .profile files if it is executed as interactive login shell. When it is executed as interactive non-login shell it reads .bashrc. Commonly it is the second case i.e when you run **gnome-terminal** bash is run as non-login shell. Applications->Accessories->Terminal is a menu entry for gnome-terminal.

Comment: Just to add a bit to this; http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles explains this more in detail, along with the history of why it is like this.  In short, put environment variables (`export MYVAR=value`) in `~/.profile`, and functions and aliases in `~/.bashrc`.