# Run a script on login using ~/.bash_login

Tags: login, scripts, logout

I need to run a script when I login and logout in my Ubuntu.

I tried to put the script in my `~/.bash_login` but it didn't work.

Is there a better location where I can run my script?

My script is located in `/home/gsd/script/login.sh` and it's executable.

edit:

my script runs when i type: `/home/gsd/script/login.sh` and it set with +x

now, i only have: `touch /home/gsd/test.txt` in the `~/.bash_login` to test.

the file test.txt is never created

edit 2:

```
gsd@laptop:~$ ll ~/.bash*
-rw------- 1 gsd gsd 38639 2012-01-25 17:25 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 gsd gsd    29 2012-01-25 15:22 .bash_login
-rw-r--r-- 1 gsd gsd   220 2011-11-03 19:22 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 gsd gsd  3136 2011-11-04 08:00 .bashrc
```

Comment: does .bash_login has the right permissions? what does ls -l .bash_login returns?

Comment: Do you also have a `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 gsd gsd 313 2012-01-22 11:56 .bash_login`

Comment: yes i have a bash profile

Comment: `chmod +x .bash_login`

Comment: By login/logout into Ubuntu, do you mean "logging in/out to the Unity/GNOME session from the graphical login manager"?

Comment: It is not necessary to `chmod +x .bash_login` (set the executable bit on .bash_login). The Bash manual is a bit confusing in this area, but Bash does not eXecute .bash_login like a shell script. It does read the file and then executes the commands within it (You can do something similar by running `source ~/.bash_login`).

Comment: @GinoSullivan : Can you provide the contents of your `~/.bash_login`? Run a few tests: Run `/home/gsd/script/login.sh` by hand, does it do what you expect? Test the `.bash_login` with the command `source ~/.bash_login`, does this do what you expect?

Comment: @StefanLasiewski do i  have to do: source ~/.bash_login everytime i login?

Comment: @Gino: No, just do that as a manual sanity check to make sure that .bash_login is doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: yes the source .bash_login works

Comment: How are you logging in to Ubuntu? SSH? Rebooting, then starting a terminal?

Answer (score 30):

If .bash_profile exists, then Bash will not read .bash_login (or .profile). This annoying feature is described in some versions of the Bash manual, but not all.

`.bash_profile` and `.bash_login`are analogous, so I recommend you put your commands in `.bash_profile`, because it's is commonly used and `.bash_login` is relatively unknown. Also consider putting your commands in `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`. The manual describes difference between "interactive non-login shell" and "interactive login shell", so be sure to read that section.

[The GNU Bash Reference Manual version 4.1: Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) says:

> looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands from **the first one that exists**
>   and is readable.

Also see [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/176404/linux-bash-not-loading-profile-in-new-session), and [this Bash howto](http://freeunix.dyndns.org:8088/site2/howto/Bash.shtml) (Don't be deterred by the freeunix.dyndns.org:8088 address--- it's still a good quality manual and I have used it for years).

**Update**, since you say you don't have a .bash_profile.

It sounds like you are not using what's called a "interactive non-login shell" (See the Bash manual for a detailed description).

To test this, add something like the following each file: `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and `.bash_login`.

```
echo "DEBUG: I am .bashrc"

echo "DEBUG: I am .bash_profile"
```

Then log out and log in again. When you log in, I bet you will only see the phrase "DEBUG: I am .bashrc" but not "I am .bash_profile". If so, it means you are a "interactive non-login shell", which simply means that Bash will call `.bashrc` but not `.bash_profile`. For information why these dotfiles are the way they are, see @Andrejs Cainikovs's post below and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

Comment: i updated my question, i don't have a bash_profile

Comment: Ok, because earlier you said "yes i have a bash profile".

Comment: yes, i had it then removed it but same results

Comment: This answer solves the problem, I think it's worth accepting it.

Comment: Also note that these bash files are only run when logging into a shell (through Terminal, ssh, etc.), not when logging into the GUI!

Comment: None of mentioned scripts runs when I'm logging in except first time after system boot.

Comment: @mivk : that's not always the case. `.bashrc` just ran for me logging in via GUI, but `.bash_login` did not.

Answer (score 9):

Login shells, regardless of if they are **interactive** or **non-interactive** read and execute the `.profile`

**Interactive shells** read and execute `.bashrc`.

Often you will see that `/etc/profile` sources `.bashrc` - thus all settings made in `.bashrc` will also take effect in a login shell regardless of whether it is interactive or non-interactive.

The order of execution of the initialization scripts for a shell is dependent on if the shell is interactive or non-interactive and not related to if it is a login script or not.

When bash is invoked as an **interactive login shell** it reads and executes commands from the `/etc/profile`. Then Bash will then try in order to execute ONLY the first file exists and is readable of the following:

1. `.bash_profile`
2. `.bash_login`
3. `.profile`

If one of these files is found but can not be read, it will cause an error. 
There is no error if any are **NOT** found.

This same process is followed when a non-interactive login shell is invoked with the `--login` option.

Comment: AFAIK, `.profile` file is read and executed only when the user logs in using the graphical interface. Otherwise it is not read.

Comment: @RajaRaviVarma I just tested (Ubuntu 16.04) and `~/.profile` definitely is read in non-graphical login shells (I tested by switching to another terminal via `Ctrl+Alt+F2` and logging in there).

Comment: I agree with @RajaRaviVarma - I'm logging into an Ubuntu 16.04 VM over SSH and `.profile` is not read, only `.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

Bash only looks for `.bash_login` or `.profile` files if it is executed as interactive login shell. When it is executed as interactive non-login shell it reads `.bashrc`.
Commonly it is the second case, i.e when you run `gnome-terminal` bash is run as non-login shell.

This clearly states that if you are booting into Gnome, `.bash_login` will not be executed. But if you lower runlevel to boot directly to bash, the same file will be executed upon succesfull login.
I assume `.bash_login` will be executed in case of remote SSH connections as well.

Partially ripped from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22403/bash-login-not-executing).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script you want to run is executable. Run `chmod +x scriptname` to do that. Also make sure the script starts with the correct shebang (`#!/bin/bash` for shell scripts). Lastly, use all full paths when executing it, e.g., `/usr/bin/echo` instead of `echo` just incase the environment that your script will execute in is not identical to the one you are used to.