# How to automatically run commands on SSH connection?

Tags: bash, ssh, scripts

I have some Amazon EC2 instances that run **Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS**.

Every time I connect to those instances I run a couple of simple commands, like a `cd <repository>`, a `git status` etc.

How can I add them to a script / to which script should I add them so they would be automatically ran every time, on SSH connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is basically to **[run a script on login](https://askubuntu.com/a/98567/4824)**.

Since Bash looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from **the first one that exists** and is readable.

I did a simple `ls -la ~`, saw that from that hierarchy `.profile` was the <del>first</del> only one available, so I just appended my commands here.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 3):

You can add all your commands in a single script and can call the script through the SSH line.

For eg. I will dump all the commands in /home/vidyadhar/commands.sh
At the time of ssh i will do it as follows
ssh vidyadhar@machine `/home/vidyadhar/commands.sh'