# Run startup applications after suspend

Tags: 12.04, startup, suspend

Is there a way to load the startup applications upon return from suspend.

My problem is that I have the line `xset m 200 1` in my start-up applications, but it won't load after suspend.

It loads fine at start-up though.

Answer (score 2):

Create a script with these contents

```
case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
        #Do nothing at 
        ;;
    thaw|resume)
        xset m 200 1
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

Set it to executable with `chmod +x foo_script_name`

Move your script to `/etc/pm/sleep.d` with `sudo mv foo_script_name /etc/pm/sleep.d`, it will be run once your computer resumes from sleep.

Comment: I just tried that, but it doesn't load

Comment: @Olivier: It most probably load, but fails. `cat /var/log/pm-suspend.log` and look for `"foo_script_name"`. The problem is that xset has no display. Updated your other Q and add a link to it here in case someone else stumble upon it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/239802/how-can-i-speed-up-my-mouse/239826#239826