# Can I give jailed users a different Welcome Message upon login?

Tags: motd

I've successfully set up a jailed user using jailkit and everything is working fine. However, I would like to provide the user with a different welcome message upon login, and keep my own existing welcome message when I log in with root.

I figured that welcome messages consist of all the scripts located in:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/*
```

I've tried creating an empty folder for my jailed user:

```
/jail/etc/update-motd.d
```

but that does not seem to work and I'm still getting the same welcome message as root user.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/98433/run-a-script-on-login-using-bash-login

Comment: You can configure the MOTD to display via the option `motd=<PATH>` of the `pam_motd` module which you can configure on a per-user or per-group basis.